# Ruby on rails querying with join and condition statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to query joining tables without using the primary key(id).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :participant
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The User has 'id' and 'name'.
The Participant has 'user_id' which is User.id

I am trying to find the Participant.id by querying with User.name

What I have tried is,

```
participant_id = Participant.all :joins => :users, :conditions => {:name => "Susie"}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you could just go User.find_by_name("Susie").participant.id..or are you looking to make a scope?

Comment: @corroded Why comment instead of answer? If you don't want to comment question but you answer it instead, then why don't you write answer?

Comment: I added a scope answer but this also seems like a good idea.

Comment: @MBO, well i was unsure what the OP was asking for. if it was a scope that would have rendered my answer useless, right?

Comment: @corroded So what? You shouldn't get -1 because OP didn't specified he needs scope. But now you get +1 on comment, which doesn't give you anything

Comment: in any case i already also posted an answer just in case the OP was looking for a specific person. if not, caley's answer is good

Comment: agree with @corroded, either way is probably a suitable answer. I'd probably use a method rather than a scope even though that's the answer I provided.

Comment: i would also use a method, mainly because i suck in making scopes with lambdas. it's not "english" enough for me haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for a specific user's participant id, you could just go:

```
User.find_by_name("Susie").participant.id
```

Since your user has a has_one relation to Participant(which belongs to it -- so basically a one-to-one) you can just go call participant on user. ActiveRecord takes care of the join magicks for you

Comment: Voted you up sir, a scope is overkill.

Comment: unless thats what mr OP wants :P (or needs)

Comment: [dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders) is what's going on here, for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :participant
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :foo, lambda {|name|
    joins(:users).
    where("name = ?", name)
  }
end
```

If you're taking user input you're going to want to probably fix joins so it uses `sanitize_sql_array`. See [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) also for some query goodness